# How to modify variables to be significant in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling

I am running a logistic regression analysis in a particular software. My objective is to study the behavior of the software with significant variables. 
However, with the data I have, there are no significant variables.

It does not matter if I modify the data and forcefully make a variable to be significant.

Any ideas how I can modify a variable so that it becomes significant?

I tried a linear combination of the output variable with different random distributions for the two values. However it did not work.

var1 = out * (random sample from distribution 1) + (1-out) * (random sample from distribution 2)

out is a binary variable (0 or 1).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could just add coppies of the data underneath each other to artificially increase the sample size. Eventually your variables will become significant.

Answer (score 1):

Make the two distributions very different.

```
Create data set 1:  OUT = 1, var1 ~ N(-10, 5), N = 100
Create data set 2:  OUT = 0, var1 ~N(10,5), N = 100
```

Merge the two and run your logistic regression.

(Since you didn't specify a language, I just wrote the above rather than R code)